# MFC: how to set font size?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I am currently using the code below to set font.

```
CFont my_font;
my_font.CreateFont(86, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                   CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, _T("Arial"));

void CMyView::OnPrint(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
    ...
    CFont *old_font = pDC->SelectObject(&my_font);
    ...
}
```

I test using print to PDF. It works ok on my machine using Microsoft Print to PDF. But when I build and run it on another machine using a very old version of Adobe PDF, the font is too small. What is the right way to set font so that its size is consistent across different machines?

Comment: The `cHeight` parameter is documented (see [CreateFontW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontw)). The `CDC` can be queried for the mapping mode ([GetMapMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#getmapmode)), and knows how to convert logical units to device units ([LPtoDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#lptodp)) and vice versa ([DPtoLP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#dptolp)).

Comment: Do you have any sample working code showing pieces connected together? Thank you for the help.